# Solving the differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx} = x^2y $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently trying to find the difference in output between the real value of this differential equation and using the RK4 method. My question is, what is the exact solution for the following equation when:
$ \frac{dy}{dx}  = x^2y $ | y(0) = 1

I don't know if this is enough information.

Comment: separate variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

You have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$$
Write it as: $$\frac{dy}y=x^2dx$$($y\neq0$)

Now integrate both sides.

Comment: Does this then result in $ y = 1/3x^3 $

Comment: @IanRonk no. You must get $$\ln y=\frac {x^3}3+c$$ as answer

Comment: and is there a way to get rid of the c?

Comment: @IanRonk yes. when you put $y(0)=1$, you can eliminate $c$

Comment: okay thank you so much will accept the answer when I can

Comment: @IanRonk did you get $c=0$?

Comment: yes I did, is that the correct answer?

Comment: @IanRonk Yes. $$y=e^{\frac{x^3}3}$$ is the correct answer

Comment: That is what I ended up with as well thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac{dy}{y}=x^2dx$$ and integrate.( for $$y\neq 0$$)